# How to add numeric pagination to Ajax result, that shows podcasts(custom post) filter by custom taxonomies

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i would like to add numeric pagination (and load the posts dynamically) to this page, called 'page-podcast', where i filter, with Ajax call, my podcast (custom post), using these tags, genre, country and type: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2hxf.jpg.

In my front end, page-podcast.php, i have this div, where post appears:

```
<div id="datafetch">Search results will appear here</div>
```

And in page function.php i added the function that call Ajax

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fetch(e){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: keywords},
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}

</script>
```

The following code is the ajax function (always on function.php):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    ...filter part, omitted, because it has nothing to do with the question...

   $the_query = new WP_Query($query_args); 

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

        <?php endwhile;
        else: ?>
        <p class="no-criteria"><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Someone has some tips/examples/code to share? Because i tried many solution that i find on the web, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
So, i have added the number of the pages within the ajax function, before the end of the loop:

```
<?php if ($numberPages > 1): ?>
<ul>
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberPages; $i++) {
        echo '<li><a name="page" href="#" class="pagination" value="' . $i . '">'
            . $i . '</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

$numberPages is equal to:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
$numberPages = $the_query->max_num_pages;
```

I create a global variable, call $page, set to 0.
Then i worked on my two event:

```
   $(document).on("click touchend", ".premuto", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        page = 1;
        keywords['page'] = page;
        keywords[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
        fetch(this);
    });
    $(document).on("click touchend", ".pagination", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        keywords[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
        fetch(this);
    });
```

".premuto" is an element that contain the id i want to pass to ajax (custom taxonomy) and page is set to 1.

".pagination" is the list of post's page number (1,2,...).

Finally, on my ajax function, i get the page number:

```
$paged = $_POST['keyword']['page'];
```

and in my wp_query i added:

```
    'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'paged' => $paged,
```